# Make all pages odd

Tags: margins, memoir, double-sided

I have a `memoir` document, with custom settings for margins, headers and footers, etc.  I just found out it is being printed single-sided instead of double-sided, and I was wondering if there is a simple command to treat all pages as odd pages.

How can I tell `memoir` to format the even pages exactly as it would the odd pages?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about adding the class option `oneside`?

P.S.: This should work for all classes featuring the `\chapter` command plus the `twoside` default option. In particular, it works for the standard class `book` and the [`KOMA-Script`](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) class `scrbook`.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly you need to use something like this:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
%%% set up the recto page layout
\checkandfixthelayout %or perhaps \checkandfixthelayout[lines]
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{\oddsidemargin}% after \checkandfix......
```

Source: Pg. 25 of the Memoir documentclass manual (Side margin section).